# “Talkin’ on the burner phone, bumpin’ hutch.”

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "[bumpin’ hutch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/wordplay/burner-phone)” mean in:

> “Talkin’ on the burner phone, bumpin’ hutch”?

From the song "One Life 2 Live" by Kingpin Skinny Pimp

"Bumping" means knock or run into someone or something with a jolt and "hutch" means a box, a cage or a storage chest, but I don't think "bumpin' hutch" means a box/cage/storage chest that is knocking or running into something ... Thank you!

Comment: That's lyrics from a song by 80s and 90s rapper Kingpin Skinny Pimp. Words in songs --and especially rap-- don't have to have the dictionary meaning, or mean anything at all. That's the case here. It's probably Memphis slang for something.

Comment: A hutch being a small box or cage one could possibly carry around, could we stretch it as far as the word being used for the phone and "bumping the hutch" just meaning "hitting the keyboard".

Comment: Based on Green's Dictionary of Slang and Urban Dictionary, bump can mean have sex with, curry favor with, kill, or rob. (Other meanings, like dance, are less likely in a car.) Hutch can mean a building or room, or a "hot ass bitch". So put together you have a lot of options, from sex or picking up women (possibly over the phone), to robbing houses (there's a mention of hot shit in the trunk, which may or may not be relevant). Good luck!

Comment: To improve the question you could quote a bit more of the lyrics, explain what the song is about, say where the artist is from, when it was released, etc, and maybe link to lyrics or YouTube video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot be sure this answer is correct, but in the absence of any explanations online for 'bumping hutch' as a phrase (I tried Google and thoroughly grilled Chat GPT) I thought the best approach would be to make observations about the two words in isolation to see if there is any logical meaning that can be drawn.

I noticed that the expression "bumping Hutch" is also in the seminal work "*Azz & Tittiez*" by Hypnotize Camp Posse, and both uses are in the context of driving a car. Further, I saw that the word 'Hutch' is capitalised in some lyrics listings for these songs, suggesting it might be a name. I wondered if it was a reference to one of the titular characters from 1970s detective series *Starsky & Hutch*, in which driving featured heavily. Both characters in the show were shown to own vehicles, but the majority of the driving was done by Starsky in his Ford Gran Torino while his partner Hutch rode 'shotgun' in the passenger seat.

To 'bump' something is slang for *removing someone or something from a particular position*. My educated guess based on the above reasoning would that 'bumping Hutch' could mean driving without a passenger, or perhaps deliberately excluding your normal driving partner.

I welcome any constructive comments that would help improve this answer, but would expect any outright dismissal of my conclusions to be backed by evidence.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!